# How to de-instrument elisp function?

Tags: edebug

To *instrument* an elisp function means to set up Emacs in such a way that whenever the function gets executed, debug mode is entered so the function can be executed stepwise. To instrument a function, move point into the definition of the function and then do `C-u C-M-x` (as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html#Using-Edebug)).

How can I de-instrument an elisp function I have instrumented so that Emacs won't stop and enter into debug mode every time I execute this function?

[According to the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Instrumenting.html#Instrumenting),

> To remove instrumentation from a definition, simply re-evaluate its definition in a way that does not instrument. There are two ways of evaluating forms that never instrument them: from a file with `load`, and from the minibuffer with `eval-expression (M-:)`.

If I use the `M-:` then the function will get executed, right? I'd like to avoid this.

So this leaves me with the second option:

> from a file with `load`

But what does it mean? Does it mean reloading the file where the function is defined by executing `C-x C-f` (or, alternatively, `M-x revert-buffer`)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `edebug`, but you can reevaluate your function's definition without instrumentation the same way you instrumented it to begin with; just omit the prefix argument: `M-x eval-defun` or `C-M-x` with point inside the function in question. Look at the documentation for `eval-defun`.

Comment: "If I use the `M-:` then the function will get executed, right?" - the idea is that you evaluate the `(defun ...)` form, not a function call.

Comment: @npostavs: How can I use `M-:` to evaluate the `(define ...)` form rather than the function call?

Comment: You put the `(defun foo () etc etc)` in answer to the `M-:` prompt (not sure I understand what your question is)